# Jenkins - use properties in a string

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to use MSDeploy to kick off an archive job, which works fine but I'd like to archive the binaries to a folder with the build number in the name. I thought use the BUILD_NUMBER prop but I can't seem to get it to expand out. It takes it as a literal. I know you need double quotes to get the expansion to happen but I've not managed to get the right incantation to do it. Any ideas?

This is a groovy script...

```
bat 'msdeploy -verb:sync -source:computerName=WEBS-02,contentpath="C:\\apps\\HDCA" -dest:computerName=WEBS-02,archivedir="c:\\apps\\HDCA${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bat '...'` should be `bat "..."` for the interpolation of `${env.BUILD_NUMBER}` to work.

Comment: Simple as that! Thanks